# Build error trying to add object to NSMutableArray singleton

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray as a singleton; when I try to add an object, I get a build error. What's wrong with the code?

Here is the singleton.h code:

```
@interface SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows : NSObject  {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayOfSelectedRows;

+ (id)sharedArrayOfSelectedRows;
@end
```

Here's the singleton.m code:

```
@implementation SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows  {

}

@synthesize arrayOfSelectedRows;  //  rename

//  sharedSelectedCellIndexes
+ (id)sharedArrayOfSelectedRows  {

static dispatch_once_t dispatchOncePredicate = 0;
__strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
dispatch_once(&dispatchOncePredicate, ^{
    _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
});

return _sharedObject;
}

-(id) init {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    arrayOfSelectedRows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Here are the lines of code where I'm getting the error:

```
    SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows *arrayOfSelectedRows = [SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows  sharedArrayOfSelectedRows];

    [arrayOfSelectedRows[indexPath.row] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];  //  reset it...
```

And this is the error:

> Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows *'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you need to subclass from NSMutableArray:

```
@interface SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows : NSMutableArray  {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arrayOfSelectedRows;

+ (id)sharedArrayOfSelectedRows;
@end
```

Comment: Be aware that NSMutableArray is a part of a class cluster which introduces some more rules when subclassing. At least if you want your class behave like a real NSMutableArray with your added functionality. See my post for documentation on this.

Comment: You should never, ever even think about subclassing NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 2):

[pNre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795621/pnre) is right. But If you really want your code to work you have two options:

1. Subclassing. This is not so easy for `NSMutableArray` because it is a class cluster. So simply subclassing it (like [ennuikiller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86837/ennuikiller) suggested) is not enough. [have a look at this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH4).
2. Object Subscripting. This is a relatively new technic introduced with Xcode 4.4. It basically allows you to override the '[]' operator for your class. Have a look at [this post](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/) if you are interested in this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows * arrayOfSelectedRows = [SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows  sharedArrayOfSelectedRows];
// this adds sets the object at index indexPath.row of the property arrayOfSelectedRows
arrayOfSelectedRows.arrayOfSelectedRows[indexPath.row] = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
```

In your code you are treating an instance of SingletonArrayOfSelectedRows as a NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

You are just confused with what you wanted.

If you change

```
+ (id)sharedArrayOfSelectedRows;
```

to

```
+ (<putherethetypethatyoureallywanted)sharedArrayOfSelectedRows;
```

then it will become quite obvious where you are going wrong.